# How to turn off news popup in KDE tray

Tags: kde

In KDE I constantly receive some news, to which I didn't subscribe. It looks like this:
[image]

Can you please explain where it comes from and how to turn it off? There is only close button on that popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are probably notifications sent by your browser generated if you give a web site permission to send you desktop notifications. Here's an example:

[image: YouTube request]

For Chromium and Google Chrome, type `chrome://settings/content/notifications` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then, enable/disable notifications as desired remembering to activate "Ask before sending".

[image: Desktop notification settings for Chromium / Google Chrome]

For Firefox, type `about:preferences#searchResults` in the address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Click on `Select` next to  `notifications` and make your choices.

[image: Desktop notification settings for Firefox]

Other browsers may have similar settings.

Comment: You were right. I granted notification permissions to a news site and it kept annoying me. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: High security risk, and forced purchase, running around like headless chicken clueless, helpless henny penny ,must be a Richard Matthew Stallman product and service